# I need to optimize a linear programming problem of a manufactoring company

Tags: optimization

A manufacturing company has a set $I = \left \{ 1,2, ..., i, ..., M \right \}$ of $M$ iron ore reduction factories. In each of these reducing factories the mineral is proccesed, producing a set $J = \left \{ 1,2, ..., j, ..., N \right \} $ of $N$ types of different iron ingots. These ingots are sent to a set $K = \left \{ 1,2, ..., k, ..., R\right \}$ of $R$ producing factories, each of which produces a set $L = \left \{ 1,2, ..., l, ..., P\right \}$ of $P$ different products. Suppose the following is known:

- One ton of iron processed in the reduction factory $i$ produces $a_{ij}$
  tons of ingots type $j$, $\forall i\in I$, $\forall j \in J$.
- From one ton of type $j$ ingots, $b_{jlk}$ tons of product $I$ are produced at production factory $k$, $\forall j \in J$, $\forall l \in L$, $\forall k \in K$.
- The maximum number of tons of ingots that can be produced in the reduction factory $i$ is $C_i$, $\forall i \in I$.
- The maximum number of tons of ingots (of all types) that can be process at production factory $k$ is $U_k$, $\forall k \in K$.
- The required quantity of tons of product type $l$ is $D_l$, $ \forall l \in L$.
- The total tonnes of ingots processed by the fabrication factories must be equal to the number of tons of ingots sent by the reduction factories.

I need to do a linear programming model that allows the manufacturing company plan its production conveniently. Considering $M = 2$; $N = 5$; $R = 3$; $P = 4$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I suspect the need is more academic in nature.